# How to redirect folder to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect an old domain that is in a folder (eg:olddomain.com/folder) to the root of a new domain (http://www.newdomain.com/).

I modified the htacess that is in the folder of the old domain with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isnt working? what happenes when you type **olddomain/folder** ?

Comment: _“an old domain that is in a folder (eg:olddomain.com/folder)”_ - do you mean that the domain is _mapped_ to that folder (i.e., calling `olddomain.com` in the browser makes it show what is in the `folder` folder), or are you visiting `olddomain.com/folder` and want only that to be redirected?

Comment: @starkeen when I type http://oldomain.com/folder, I go to http://olddomain.com/folder instead of http://www.newdomain.com/

Comment: Ie this is **/dir/.htaccess** , You need to remove the **folder/** from your pattern as the rule is relative to that directory.. **^(.*)$** should work.

Comment: @CBroe on the root domain, I have a page http://olddomain.com/ and in a folder I have other pages: http://olddomain.com/folder/page1, http://olddomain.co/folder/page2..... I want to redirect them all to the root of the new domain.

Comment: _“I have a page `olddomain.com`”_ - a domain is not a page, and a page is not a domain ... this makes little sense. Next try: So you want to redirect only requests of the form `olddomain.co/folder/...`, anything inside that folder - but users accessing only `olddomain.com/` should stay on that address, and not be redirected? Same for `olddomain.co/someotherfolder/`, no redirect in that case either?

Comment: @CBroe I want to redirect all the requests of olddomain.com/folder/ and also olddomain.com/ to newdomain.com. There is no other folder.

Comment: Well if you want to redirect everything, then why are you specifically checking for `^folder/(.*)$` in your RewriteRule? And why are you appending the match again after the new domain, if you say you want to redirect everything to the root anyway?

Comment: @starkeen So this should be: 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]

  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>`
Thanks.

Comment: @CBroe at first, I had written the following  and placed it in the htaccess at the root of the old domain, but it wasn't working. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. The URL `http://olddomain.com` was redirecting to `http://www.newdomain.com`, but `http://olddomain.com/folder` wasn't redirecting.